# Is there a technique to determine if a dos app was invoked via sentto vs a dos window?

Tags: winapi, windows-xp, console, visual-c++-6, sendto

In the case of a sendto invocation, I would like to keep the application open, after it completes, so the user can look at it.

In the case of a dos window invocation, the user controls when the window closes.

The platform is XP using msvc 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortcut you create in the SendTo folder can call:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k [your program path\program name]
```

The `/k` will keep the console up after the invocation.